# R how to save data to CSV without " string separator written

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv

How to write a data frame of character values to CSV file with `;` as separator between columns and NO `"` sign (and no any other sign) marking the beginning and the end of a char passage?

```
write.table(my.df, file = "my_data.csv", row.names=FALSE, na="", col.names=FALSE, sep=";")
```

results in:

```
"abc";"abc2";"abc3"
(...)
```

whereas I would like to have:

```
abc;abc2;abc3
(...)
```

Comment: You probably want `write.csv2()` rather than `write.table(sep = ";")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `quote = FALSE`:

```
> write.table(letters[1:3], quote = FALSE, sep = ';')
x
1;a
2;b
3;c
```